# QTP/UFT : To perform an action on object which is retrived from Object Repository file (.tsr)

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

My objective is to  get an object from Object Repository file (.tsr) and perform some action on that object like click, set...
In the below code "WebButton" object is captured. But when I perform "click" action on this object (brObj). Getting error message in UFT " The test run cannot continue due to unrecoverable error line(20):brObj.Click "

```
  Dim RepositoryFrom, brObj
  Dim ObjectRepositoryPath, str, pgStr, btnStr  

  ObjectRepositoryPath="C:\Repository2.tsr"

  Set RepositoryFrom = CreateObject("Mercury.ObjectRepositoryUtil")
  RepositoryFrom.Load ObjectRepositoryPath

  str = "Browser("+""""+"Title"+""""+")"
  pgStr = "Page("+""""+"Title"+""""+")"
  btnStr = "WebButton("+""""+"Login"+""""+")"

  'MsgBox str 

  set brObj =  RepositoryFrom.GetObject(str+"."+pgStr+"."+btnStr) 
  brObj.Click 'Getting error for this line
```

So is there another way in UFT to perform an action on object which is retrived

from Object Repository file (.tsr)

Answer (score 1):

The COM objects you access from that library are not the same objects the UFT run-time engine uses during playback.  If you want to load an object repository file at run-time, you can use the RepositoriesCollection utility object to add the file to the available object repositories.  Once loaded, you can access the test objects like you would any other test object in UFT.

```
Dim ObjectRepositoryPath, brObj

ObjectRepositoryPath = "C:\Repository2.tsr"
RepositoriesCollection.Add ObjectRepositoryPath

Set brObj = Browser("Title").Page("Title").WebButton("Login")
brObj.Click
```

Comment: Right. The `RepositoryFrom.GetObject(str+"."+pgStr+"."+btnStr)` is a COM object representing the repo entry. It is not the test object suitable for playback.

Comment: Yes I got it. But there is an another way to get the test object from the string using the "Execute" statement and it is  suitable for playback. 
Execute "set brObj = "+str+"."+pgStr+"."+btnStr
brObj.Click

Answer (score 0):

There is an another way to get the test object from the string using the "Execute" statement and it is  suitable for playback.

```
str = "Browser("+""""+"Title"+""""+")"
pgStr = "Page("+""""+"Title"+""""+")"
btnStr = "WebButton("+""""+"Login"+""""+")"
Execute "set brObj = "+str+"."+pgStr+"."+btnStr"
brObj.Click
```

Comment: Yes, this will technically work, but is totally unnecessary and will make your code hard to read.

Comment: In QTP our script will be like as shown below:
Browser("").Page("").WebButton().set ""
Browser("").Page("").Link().Click

Every time we need to write Browser.Page.Frame...

But if we get the button or any other object path from Object Repository file (.tsr) in string like "Browser("").Page("").WebButton()" by just passing the logical name of the object then it is not necessary to write "Browser.Page.Frame" every in our script.

We can get the  test object from the string using the "Execute" statement and it is suitable for playback.

Comment: If you think this is what helped you, please accept your own answer so that this question gets closed, and disappears from the list of open questions.